# Python if function across a vector

Tags: python, function, if-statement, vector, indexing

I'm new to Python and trying to work out how to do the following.

### I have a data array, X, which looks something like:

```
X = [ 1 2 3

      4 5 6 

      7 8 9 

      10 11 12];
```

Such that the first column `X[0]` is,

```
X[0] =[1
       4
       7
       10];
```

the second column `X[1]` is,

```
X[1] =[2
       5
       8
       11];
```

and third column `X[2]` is,

```
X[2] =[3
       6
       9
       12];
```

What I want to do is generate a single random number, `k`, and if any of the values in the first column `X[0]` are greater than `k` I want to multiply the third column by a function (`2*X[0]`), and if any of the values are less than `k` I want to multiply by a different function (`2*k`).

So if `k=2`, the third column becomes:
and third column `X[2]` is,

```
X[2] =[3*2*k
       6*2*X[0,1]
       9*2*X[0,2]
       12*2*X[0,3] ];
```

Is there a succinct way to do this?

Comment: You're not using arrays correctly.  In this case, the array is malformed

Comment: Correct array usage would be `x = [ [1, 4, 7, 10] , [2, 5, 8, 11] , [3, 6, 9, 12] ]`.

You need to make sure you use commas and nested arrays to get the `x[0]` `x[1]` `x[2]` behavior you desire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# inverted your rows and columns and got them in a list of list
X = [[1,4,7,10],
     [2,5,8,11],
     [3,6,9,12]]

# lets generate random number k between 0 and 1000
import random
k = random.randint(0, 1000)

# the conditional
for n in X[0]:
    if n > k:
        X[2] = your_function(X[2])
    if n < k:
        X[2] = your_other_function(X[2])
```

I'm pretty sure there are better ways to do this, but this one seems simple enough. Of course your_function and your_other_function are up to you, I wasn't really clear on what you wanted to in any case.

Also, have you thought this through? The only way the two functions won't be applied if all the values in X[0] are exactly equal to k, which seems unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

```
X = [
    [ 1, 4, 7, 10 ],
    [ 2, 5, 8, 11 ],
    [ 3, 6, 9, 12 ] ]

def mapping(x):
    if x[0] < K: return x[1]*2*K
    elif x[0] > K: return x[1]*2*x[0]
    else: return x[1]

K = 2
X[2] = map(mapping, zip(X[0], X[2]))
```